# Сложить числа из заданного диапазона

Tags: kotlin

Примитивная задача с SoloLearn. Нужно сложить числа из заданного диапазона. Решение должно быть очень простым.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    val lit1 = readLine()!!.toInt()
    val lit2 = readLine()!!.toInt()

    for (x in lit1..lit2){

    }    
}
```

Comment: Сколько в приведенном коде Ваших строк?

Comment: ну всё кроме main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun main() {
    val lit1 = readLine()!!.toInt()
    val lit2 = readLine()!!.toInt()

    var sum = 0
    for (x in lit1..lit2) {
        sum += x
    }
    println(sum)
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Что за глупый наезд?

Comment: это всего лишь пожелание ориентироваться на [хорошие ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa)